# Rails track user clicks if link to another website

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to track user clicks on the link, the difficulty is I want to track only external link clicks, for example if my site is www.railssite.com and I have to links www.railssite.com and www.google.com. I want to track only the google.com clicks. how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to do that.

1. You can use 3rd tracking service e.g. Google Analytics
2. Write it your self a custom controller that help you track user clicks, but in this way you will have to change your external link to something like this: `http://YOUR_WEBSITE/redirect_to=http://google.com`. Then your controller will count the clicks of users of any website of your choice before redirect user to external website.